# Multiplying variable times a multiplier gets stuck way below max

Tags: javascript, algorithm, dynamic

I'm writing an algorithm that takes 25 positions on a leaderboard and determines how much each rank in the leaderboard gets paid.

Pay is suppose to be paid out to each rank on a what I can describe best as a singularity curve (not great at math so I'm sure theres a term for this).

At each step of the curve corresponding to the leaderboard, the multiplier increases...1st gets a much greater multiplier than 25th.

I am trying to write this out so after the algorithm iterates through 25 positions in an inner while loop, it assesses weather the initial multiplier reaches the total pot for the leaderboard after hitting all 25 positions and if it doesn't it increases the multiplier by a decimal point and goes back into the inner while loop.

It seems as though that trying this, when I try to multiply the 'payRunner' by the multiplier, it gets stuck at a decimal number far below the max. I imagine this is a perfect problem for DP but wanted to just get a working solution first...so ideas of a DP solution to refactor this to is greatly appreciated but not necessary. Any ideas???

My code:

```
const payCurve = (subscription) => {
  let max = 3 * (subscription * 25);
  let maxReached = false;
  let multiplier = 1.01;
  let payRunner = 25;
  let total = 0;
  let ranks = 25;
  let count = 1;

  while (maxReached == false) {
    while (count <= ranks) {
      payRunner *= multiplier
      count ++
    }
    if (payRunner < max) {
      multiplier += 0.01
    }
    console.log(payRunner)

    if (payRunner > max) {
      maxReached = true
    }
  }
}
 payCurve(50)
```

Comment: Figure out in advance what you want the percentages to be for each position. Then you can just multiply each percentage by the total pot value.

Comment: To be a bit more specific: Do this assignment of pay for each player with an arbitrary start value. Calculate the total amount that you would pay with this assignment. And finally multiply each pay by `availableMoney / totalMoney`.

Comment: This is very confusing. Do you mean an exponentially decreasing curve? Shouldn't you reset count before the inner while? Why is max 3 * 25 * subscription? What is subscription, the total?

Comment: @Nico thanks, I'll give that a try

Comment: @maraca yes, exponentially decreasing start from 1st down to 25th. Max is the total pot, which is $50 per competitor - 25 competitors total - putting that $50 into the pot each month for 3 months

Comment: @maraca - and yes count should be reset before the inner while loop, thanks for catching that

Comment: I am not sure if you have defined your function. In case it is open and you just have implemented by "trials & errors" you may want to simply define yourself how the prize repartition should look like (without caring about the ```50$``` pot). Once you have your x and associated ```y$```, just sum every ```y$``` and divide every ```y``` by the same ratio ```c```. e.g ( for two guys, value you defined are ```60``` and ```40```, sum is ```100```, pot is ```50$```, ```100/50=2```,  divide everybody by ```2``` => ```30``` and ```20``` (and obviously now your pot is indeed ```50$```)

Comment: If I understand you want to split some total amount `n` among `p` people using an exponential curve. The formula for this is: `a * b^x`. So an easy way to do this is to say first gets `t` times more money than last. This means first gets `y`, last gets `y / t`. Then you know `a = y` and `y * b ^ (p - 1) = y / t`. After solving you have expressed `a` and `b` in `y` and `y` is defined by `y * (1 + b + b^2 + ... + b^(p - 1)) = n`.

Comment: You can make it easy by setting `y = t` then calculate `a` (which is the same as t) and `b`, calculate how much everybody gets like this. Then you scale so that the sum is equal to the total amount, as already mentioned by others.